# Rolle' Theorem on Second Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, rolles-theorem

Suppose that the function $f$ has second derivative in the interval $(a,b)$ and that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)=f(x_3)$, with $a < x_1<x_2<x_3<b$. Then, there exist a $\epsilon \in (a,b)$, such that $f''(\epsilon) = 0.$

**My Attempt:**

I am going to use Rolle Theorem on that problem.
Basically, Rolle Theorem gives us, exist a $\delta_1, \delta _2$ such that
$$f'(\delta_1) = \frac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1} = 0$$
$$f'(\delta_2) = \frac{f(x_2) - f(x_3)}{x_2 - x_3} = 0.$$
So, if $g(x) = f'(x)$, then
$$g'(\epsilon) = \frac{g(\delta_2) - g(\delta_1)}{\delta_2 - \delta_1} = 0.$$
Is it true?

Comment: That works, maybe also write that since $f$ is double differentiable, it follows that $f$ and $f'$ are differentiable on the required interval.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Thankyou for the answer. 
Actually I am doubt about the existance of first derivative of $f$. 
I dont know.. $f''$ is known exist, but $f'$ remain unknown.

Comment: @Niccolo $f''$ is the derivative of the first derivative, so how can $f''$ exists without the existence of $f'$?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is twice differentiable it follows straight from Rolle's theorem.